# How to delete all records from the tableA based on the given join condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, vba

Here the code I am using to populate the records:

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON (tableA.CASE = tableB.case_id_txt)
AND (tableA.COMPANY = act_req_t.company_txt)
AND (tableA.[CLIENT ID] = tableB.client_id_txt)
WHERE (((tableB.status_txt)="Open"));
```

Now instead of populating, I want those records to be deleted but my below code does not work. It keeps prompting "Could not delete from specified tables"

```
DELETE tableA
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON (tableA.CASE = tableB.case_id_txt)
AND (tableA.COMPANY = tableB.company_txt)
AND (tableA.[CLIENT ID] = tableB.client_id_txt)
WHERE (((tableB.status_txt)="Open"));
```

Where is the issue here?

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS / database engine are you using, and where is an example of the actual VBA code that is being used to execute the query?

Comment: DELETE
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tableB
        WHERE a.[CASE] = tableB.case_id_txt
            AND a.COMPANY = tableB.company_txt
            AND a.[CLIENT ID] = tableB.client_id_txt
            AND tableB.status_txt = 'Open'
        )

Comment: if you hover over the tag "sql" it states that: *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.* **Please** use tag your question with the actual dbms being used - it makes a difference to how quickly you can get an answer.

Comment: `DELETE FROM ... JOIN ...` is a non-standard syntax. Which dbms are you using? Also note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: I am using MS Access query to run the code.
I tried this one,:
DELETE FROM tableA a WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableB WHERE a.[CASE] = tableB.case_id_txt AND a.COMPANY = tableB.company_txt AND a.[CLIENT ID] = tableB.client_id_txt AND tableB.status_txt = 'Open' )

It's working, however, the populating query shows 2259 records but when running the code above, it only delete 1986 records.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the above solution works. My data contains duplicated records that's why.

Thank you very much!